# get_close_matches identify values

Tags: python

I have the following problem.
I want to search a list of strings for strings that match a string. This works quite well with difflib.get_close_matches.
The problem is that I often have the same strings and need to know which is which.
How it should work:

```
my_list = [["apple", 2], ["banana", 3], ["apple", 1]]
result = get_close_matches("ap", my_list)
print(result)
[["apple", 2], ["apple", 1]]
```

I hope you understand what I mean.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to utilize the "in" operator in your function.  Following is a snippet of code illustrating that function.

```
def get_close_matches(st, mylist):
    newlist = []
    
    for item in mylist:
        if (st in item[0]):
            newlist.append(item)
            
    return newlist
            
            
my_list = [["apple", 2], ["banana", 3], ["apple", 1]]

result = get_close_matches("ap", my_list)
print(result)
```

This was the result on my terminal of running that code snippet.

```
@Una:~/Python_Programs/FindString$ python3 FindString.py 
[['apple', 2], ['apple', 1]]
```

Give that a try.